# rigify problems generating a rig

Tags: rigify

I'm having a problem using the add-on 'rigify', I line up the rig to my model then generate the rig but it creates a strange group of empty circles around the vertices of the rig rather than the rig.[image]

Answer (score 0):

you may have disconnected or deleted something on your meta-rig before creating it. Retry with a fresh meta-rig and hit the "generate" button to check if it works. You can still delete the rig object and re-generate another from time to time to check everything works... until your meta-rig is perfectly placed !